# settext to edit text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an activity and it has theme as dialog .
inthis activity, 10 edit text's are there. for one edit box  i am unable to set text to the edit box.

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     
    is_tablet=SharedVariables.sharedPrefDate.getBoolean("isTablet", false);
    if(!is_tablet){
        super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
    }
    //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_bottom_to_top,0);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity=UpdateCasePersonAddressScreen.this;
    setContentView(R.layout.update_person_address_screen);



    //allocating memory to objBLAddCasePersonScreenOperations
    objBLAddPersonAddressScreenOperations=new BLAddUpdatePersonAddressScreenOperations();
    objBLCommonOperations=new BLCommonOperations(); 
    getAllIds();


    //objPersonAddress=new clsPersonAddress();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    //code to get all objects using Bundle from previous activity
    if(bundle!=null){

        objPersonAddress = (clsPersonAddress) bundle.getParcelable("clsPersonAddress");
        System.out.println("from Extras");
        bundle=null;
    }        



    initTextFields();
    inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    /* if (inputMethodManager != null) {
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }*/
}
public void initTextFields(){

    updatePersonAddressTitleEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressTitle());
    updatePersonAddressMemoEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressMemo());
    updatePersonAddressNameEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressName());
    updatePersonAddressBusinessNameEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressBusinessName());
    updatePersonAddressWorkPhoneEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressWorkPhone());
    updatePersonAddressHomePhoneEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressHomePhone());
    updatePersonAddressMobilePhoneEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressMobilePhone());
    updatePersonAddressAddressLine1EditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressLine1());
    updatePersonAddressAddressLine2EditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressLine2());
    updatePersonAddressCityEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressCity());

    System.out.println("objPersonAddress.getAddressState()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"+objPersonAddress.getAddressState());

    updatePersonAddressStateEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressState().toString());//setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressState(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    System.out.println("updatePersonAddressStateEditText text is now is:"+updatePersonAddressStateEditText.getText().toString()+"null check:"+updatePersonAddressStateEditText.toString());
    System.out.println("below objPersonAddress.getAddressState()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))"+objPersonAddress.getAddressState());

    updatePersonAddressZipEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressZip());
    updatePersonAddressCountryEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressCountry());
}
```

can any body help me in this issue.For any help thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. provide your code so that we could know what mistake you are making. We can't simply find your problem with this.

Comment: Where is the code of the other 9 text boxes?

Comment: my code line is updatePersonAddressStateEditText.setText(objPersonAddress.getAddressState()); from that object i got the data next I wrote like  this but it isnot setting the text to the edit text.

Comment: Put a log and check if objPersonAddress.getAddressState() is empty

Comment: it has the data i was p[rinted above below of above code it is  returning data properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android native:

```
String text = "Example";
EditText edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
edtText.setText(text);`
```

Look! EditText accept only String values, if necessary convert to String.

if int, double, long value, do:

```
String.value(value);
```

Exemple:

```
int i = 5;
edtText.setText(String.value(i));
```

Android annotations:

```
@ViewById
EditText edtText;
```

To set:

```
@UiTread
void setText(){
    edtText.setText("Text");
}
```

To call:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    this.setText();
}
```

Comment: my value is string itself not other data types

Comment: i have edited my question with my code please check there.

Comment: I identified the mistake the problem is the filter that is set to that Edittext.I got what i want.Thanks a lot  for your response.

Answer (score 4):

```
EditText edit;// define it before onCreate

edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext); //get it from xml

String value="123";
//simply use 

edit.setText(value);
```

Comment: it is also not working.thanks!!

Comment: simply try to set static value... If it works then code is fine.. And check value in log cat or toast that you want to set.You need to fallow step in reverse order in order to check whether value is getting or not

Answer (score 1):

just write down like this

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.setText("abc");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . But it not working.

Comment: can u post your code...what's error come ?

Comment: There no error my code is in the above comment.Pleasecheck

Comment: just write .toString end of objPersonAddress.getAddressState() link. or just check EditText.setText("abc") set static is set or not ?

Comment: I set the static value as EditText.setText("abc cde"); also  but if write EditText.setText("abc") it setting for the spaced data only the problem

Comment: means edttest.settext is ok but please check (objPersonAddress.getAddressState()) data and Log.i("objPersonAddress.getAddressState()",""+objPersonAddress.getAddressState());

Comment: check log data will print or not ?

Comment: can u post your this code part.

Comment: i have edited my question with my code please check there.